# How to set visual studio to autogenerate control code

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have problem. In this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg638943[^]

we can see that code is automatically generated. But when I drag and drop some entity in the same way, visual studio generate only this:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Testowy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource taktTimerEntitiesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("taktTimerEntitiesViewSource")));
            // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
            // taktTimerEntitiesViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
        }
    }
}
```

I have visual studio 2012. I tried the same in Visual Studio 2010 Express but situation was the same. Can somebody help?

Comment: have you made sure to check the other part of the class. A control in .NET is normally separated into two files. Take a look inside the InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: It is WPF. InitializeComponent is autogenerated.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Asking us to take a look at a 31 minute video to see what you mean is a little much. You're looking to understand why it didn't create the query code around your entity in the code behind as it does with video.

Comment: Yes, in first minutes woman create list box, drag and drop entity into this list box and in Window.cs visual studio auto generate code (GetCustomerQuery) but my visual studio generate only this above.